# Thread Safe Generic List block Enumeration

Tags: c#, vb.net, list

First I would like to state that I have looked up probably a hundred google, and stackoverflow questions related to my question.  I cannot find anything that answers my specific question.

I converted a DataTable into a List.  I have multiple threads that enumerate the List with foreach.  However, once every 5 minutes a master thread needs to refresh that List with the latest data.  When this occurs, I need to block other threads from reading the thread until the master thread has fully updated the List.

All the articles and questions I have found blocks access on the single add.  I know I can write a blocking for the update, but I need that lock to be also syncronized with all the other threads that enumerate.  I do not want to update the List while other threads are in middle of their own enumeration.

How can I write a lock that will be utilized foreach statements and also for my update function?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I want to block "Consumers / Observers" when the producer thread is producing.  I do not want Consumers / Observers blocking each other.

Comment: ReaderWriterLock will be ideal for such a scenario, where at a given time one thread writes and many threads can read, however only write or read can happen at a given point of time

Comment: Your question is not specific: it is the classic **producer/consumers** problem (in your case it is more a **producer/observers**, but the issue is the same). It is heavily documented on the web. I find it curious that you couldn't find anything about it. It can be solve with [semaphors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) or [monitors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx).

Comment: Check:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/readerwriterlockslim-class-in-C-Sharp-threading/

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I'd suggest `ReaderWriterLockSlim` over `ReaderWriterLock` for pretty much anything using .NET 3.5 or later.

Comment: I need to block consumers/observers when producer is producing.  I do not want consumers to block each other though.

Comment: @Besticles That is exactly what a ReaderWriterLock does, it allows unlimited consumers untill a producer needs to write. It then block all consumers till the single producer is done then allows all the consumers again.

Comment: @Jon Hanna agreed, my idea was to promote ReaderWriterLock, assuming newer and efficient implementation would be discovered as part of OP's research :)

Answer (score 0):

Put all code that populates and enumerates the list in a lock block:

```
    lock (theList)
    {
       Update(theList);
    }

    lock (theList)
    {
       foreach (var thingy in theList)
       {
         DoStuff(thingy);
       }
    }
```

Comment: And now you've blocked all the reading threads from working coherently, even though they won't cause each other any difficulty.

Comment: Very bad design, it will synchronize access of all the threads, multiple threads cannot even read in this case

Comment: My impression is that the OP is looking for very basic thread sync. techniques. Maybe I misread. Explaining how to implement a many reader/one writer lock primitive seemed far out of scope.

Comment: Why would you implement one when the framework already provides two?

Answer (score 0):

At first I though you could try to use a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). It implements the producer/consumer problem.

What you need actually is a way to set a **rendez-vous** for your reading threads and your master thread.

I think this can be done with monitors (especially by using [Wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait.aspx) and [Pulse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx) methods). Try it and tell us what you found.

Comment: Thanks Kryptos, I will let you know.